# What does it mean when a question says that F and B lie on the same side as the line through A C?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, angle

I came across this question:

> In the triangle $ABC$, $\angle BAC = w$ and $\angle CBA = 2w$, where $2w$ is acute, and $BC = x$.
>
> 1. Show that $AB = (3 + 4 \sin(w))x$.
> 2. The point $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and the point $E$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$. Find an expression for $DE$ in terms of $x$.
> 3. The point $F$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and is a distance $x$ from $C$. The points $F$ and $B$ lie on the same side of the line through $A$ and $C$. Show that the line $FC$ trisects the $\angle ACB$.

But I don't quite understand what is meant by $F$ and $B$ lie on the same side of the line via $A$ and $C$?
Can someone please explain this to me?

Thank you!

[image: AngleTrisection]

As shown in this diagram, for very small $\enspace\pmb{\omega}$, $\enspace\pmb{F}\space$ can lie outside $\triangle ABC$. For larger $\enspace\pmb{\omega}\left(\le 45^o\right)$, $\space\pmb{F}\space$ lies inside $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "But I don't quite understand what is meant by F and B lie on the same of the line via A and C?" -- Any given line, if extended infinitely in both directions, divides the plane into two halves. The statement says, then, $F,B$ lie on the same half-plane.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer does that mean that in this case F is within the triangle?

Comment: The expression given for $AB$ in the part (1) of the question is wrong. The correct expression is $$\\ AB=\left(1+2\cos\left(2\omega\right)\right)x$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend the perpendicular bisector "up" further from $D$ you can locate another point $F'$ on it at distance $x$ from $C$. If you extend the segment $AC$ in both directions to a line, then $F$ and $B$ are on the same side of that line while $F'$ and $B$ are on opposite sides. You have to use that fact somehow in your proof, which will fail if you try for $F'$.

Neither $F$ nor $F'$ need be inside the triangle. Clearly $F$ is not in the picture.

(The picture does not show   $E$. )

Comment: The diagram you refer to in your explanation was posted by us. It was now updated to suit your answer. If you wish you may delete the bracketed last sentence.

Comment: @YNK I edited my comment.